# $_POST not triggering when submitting form and passing variable data via URL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Simple CRUD app.
Main list holds several children
When deleting a child I am passing the parentID and the childID to my deleteItem script 'deleteitem.php.'

**table being rendered from database information**

```
<form action="deleteitem.php" method="post">

<?php

$var = 1;
$listID = $_GET['listID'];

$select = "SELECT subtasks.createdOn, subtasks.subtask_id, subtasks.listTitle, subtasks.createdBy, subtasks.listStatus, subtasks.createdOn
           FROM subtasks
           INNER JOIN userlists 
           ON subtasks.parentID = userlists.listID
           WHERE subtasks.isChild = :var
           AND subtasks.parentID = :listID";
$select = $pdo->prepare($select);
$select->bindParam(':var',$var);
$select->bindParam(':listID',$listID);
$select->execute();

while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $listID = $row['subtask_id'];
    $listTitle = $row['listTitle'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$createdOn = $row['createdOn']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$listTitle = $row['listTitle']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$listStatus = $row['listStatus']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a class=\"btn btn-warning\" href='edit.php?edit_id=$listID'";
    echo "</a><i class=\"fa fa-pencil-square-o\"></i>";
    echo "<a>";
    echo " ";
    echo "<a href='deleteitem.php?listID=$listID&parentID=$parentID'>";
    echo "<input=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" value=name=\"deleteItem\"/>";
    echo "<i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i></a>";
    echo "<a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>

</tbody>
</form>
```

**deleteitem.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

/**Include our MySQL connection.*/
require 'database.php';

$listID = $_GET['listID'];
$parentID = $_GET['parentID'];

try {
    if(isset($_POST['deleteItem'])) {

        $delete = "DELETE FROM subtasks 
                   WHERE subtask_id = :listID 
                   AND parentID = :parentID";
        $delete = $pdo->prepare($delete);
        $delete->bindParam(':listID',$listID);
        $delete->bindParam(':parentID',$parentID);
        $delete->execute();

        $listID = $parentID;

        header("location:list.php?listID=$listID&parentID=$parentID");
        echo 'The delete happened';
    }
    /* catch any exceptions that may occur */
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "error:".$e->getMessage();
}

echo 'Parent ID ';
var_dump($parentID);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'List ID ';
var_dump($listID);

?>
```

My var_dump lines are outputting the parentID and listID so I know the data is being pushed to the deleteitem.php file. For some reason however, the DELETE statement is not running at all.

Any help figuring out why the DELETE statement is not executing would be appreciated.

Comment: `$_POST` does not use a url, `$_GET` does.

Comment: A link doesn't submit a form only a `submit`/`input`  does, or with some JS.

Comment: You are not too good at accepting answer lately. Why should the SO community help you if you never leave a TIP

Comment: I assume you are talking to me. If someone answers my post and it is the answer that does in fact work, I mark it as accepted. Just because someone post something doesnt warrant they get credit for the answer. Are you going to complain further if there are multiple answers and I pick the answer you wouldnt pick?

In fact, your post doesnt offer any assistance at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['deleteitem']` will only be present if you press the submit button.

If you click the anchor tag you created here:

```
echo "<a href='deleteitem.php?listID=$listID&parentID=$parentID'>";
```

You will not be sending to the php with POST but instead with GET. Also only the variables that exist on the querystring i.e. `?listID=$listID&parentID=$parentID` will be passed, so not `deleteItem`.

So this IF Test line will never be true if you click the anchor tag

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteItem'])) {
```

Comment: Let me look at it.

Comment: That makes sense. That would explain why the `DELETE` statement never actually runs. I got rid of `if(isset($_POST['deleteItem'])) {` so now the statement just runs when the page is called. Works like a champ!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is used for `POST` method, `$_GET` for `GET` method. `$_REQUEST` works on both.